Zero-knowledge Cross-Chain
I have an idea about integrating ZKP (Zero-Knowledge Proof) into XCM communication. Currently, when performing cross-chain operations between two parachains, we need to go through a relay and open an HRMP channel. My proposal is to add modular ZKP into the parachain, with the goal of concealing tokens and other sensitive information. Since this is a test environment, the ZKP task would be a relatively small problem to solve. I think the way it works is that we will first take the relay chain as the base to allow two parachains to communicate with each other. After that, if the two parachains want to continue communicating, there needs to be an additional authentication mechanism in place. I think this could be ZKP.
The core idea behind this is to view the relay like a company and the parachains like individual employees. The relay may not want other parachains to check its transactions. If verification is necessary, ZKP would be required.
I think i can add pallet or something, and give me where is parachain template
Do you have any ideas or keywords that could help with this? I’d appreciate your input.
Contact me if you can:
Discord: baolodc
Gmail: hpgbao@gmail.com
